# How to use sed to remove endings on strings in text file?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have the following text file, which is one long column of strings:

```
$ cat file1.txt

tags
rs:23269:DFDAB:18/1
rs:10760:DFDAB:160/1
rs:97759:DFDAB:0/2
rs:17278:DFDAB:013/1
rs:7323:DFDAB:548/2
rs:1236:DFDAB:4336/1
rs:1256:DFDAB:2373/1
```

These strings need to have the ending `/1` or `/2` removed. I think `sed` would be the best for this (or perhaps another regex-friendly tool, e.g. perl)

I think `sed 's/[0-9]+$//' file1.txt` will remove all integers at the end of each string, but how do I remove `/#`?

Is there another choice more efficient that `sed`?

Comment: @randomir yes, forward-slash and an integer (see edit above; sorry about that)

Comment: please check my solution once too on same.

Comment: *"Is there another choice more efficient that sed?"* -- what makes you think `sed` is not efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slash needs to be backslashed not to mean the substitution delimiter:

```
sed 's/\/[0-9]$//'
```

You can use a different delimiter to avoid the need to backslash:

```
sed 's=/[0-9]$=='
```

For Perl, the substitution is exactly the same, you just need the `-p` flag to print the output, and `-e` to introduce the code to evaluate:

```
perl -pe 's=/[0-9]$=='
```

Comment: Now, just add `awk 'sub(/\/[0-9]$/,"")'`, and we're done here. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be forward-slash. See edit above. Sorry about that!

Comment: Updated. My awk-fu is weak, is it `awk '{sub("/[0-9]$","");print}'`?

Comment: @choroba, that awk should fly sir.

Comment: @choroba, either that, or the one above.. Which can be even shorter, yes, `awk 'sub("/[0-9]$","")'`..

Answer (score 1):

You haven't showed your sample Input_file for removing # at the last of the line so I edited your shown Input_file  bit. Let's say following is the Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
tags
rs:23269:DFDAB:18/21
rs:10760:DFDAB:160/1
rs:97759:DFDAB:0/2
rs:17278:DFDAB:013/1
rs:7323:DFDAB:548/2
rs:1236:DFDAB:4336/1
rs:1256:DFDAB:2373/1
rs:1236:DFDAB:4336/#
rs:1256:DFDAB:2373/#
```

Then following sed may help here to remove digits at last and # at last too.

```
sed 's/\/[0-9]*$//;s/\/#$//'   Input_file
tags
rs:23269:DFDAB:18
rs:10760:DFDAB:160
rs:97759:DFDAB:0
rs:17278:DFDAB:013
rs:7323:DFDAB:548
rs:1236:DFDAB:4336
rs:1256:DFDAB:2373
rs:1236:DFDAB:4336
rs:1256:DFDAB:2373
```

In case your Input_file doesn't have # in them then please use only following.

```
sed 's/\/[0-9]*$//' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Below one liner will give you the desired output

```
perl -pi -e "s/\/[0-9]+$|\/#+$//g" file1.txt
```

out put:

```
rs:23269:DFDAB:18
rs:10760:DFDAB:160
rs:97759:DFDAB:0
rs:17278:DFDAB:013
rs:7323:DFDAB:548
rs:1236:DFDAB:4336
rs:1256:DFDAB:2373
```

where:

```
\/[0-9]+$ : anything ending with '/' followed by [any number between 0-9]

 (or)

#+$       : one or more '#'
```